# nslookup not working on route-53 public hosted zone

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, dns-zone, amazon-route53

I created a new record set example.my.domain.com in the public hosted zone my.domain.com and when I'm trying to do, "nslookup example.my.example.com", it's not working. This is the response of nslookup:

```
Server:     10.224.0.2
Address:    10.224.0.2#53
** server can't find example.my.example.com: NXDOMAIN
```

I already went through these solutions...

- [sub-subdomain records for public hosted zone in AWS not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/741071/sub-subdomain-records-for-public-hosted-zone-in-aws-not-working) .
- [How can I troubleshoot a Route 53 hosted zone?](https://serverfault.com/questions/606880/how-can-i-troubleshoot-a-route-53-hosted-zone) .
- [nslookup does not work on certain IP address](https://serverfault.com/questions/659058/nslookup-does-not-work-on-certain-ip-address) .

Didn't work!

Comment: If you're down-voting, at least explain why!

Comment: It'd help if you'd stop censoring the domain so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you have also a private route53 zone for "my.domain.com" you must set the internal vpc address (`10.224.0.<ip>`), because when you have both public and private zones, then the public zone is not propagated by the internal VPC resolvers.

you have 2 solutions:

a) remove the private zone (if you do not need it)

b) register `example.my.domain.com` also in the private zone using its private address